# open half-disk is homeomorphic to upper half-plane

Tags: general-topology

Let $A=[0,\infty)\times\mathbb{R}$ (upper half-plane) and $B=[0,a)\times(c,d)$ (open half-disk) then $[0,\infty)$ is homeomorphic to $[0,a)$ and $\mathbb{R}$ is homeomorphic to $(c,d)$. Why is their product also homeomorphic?

Comment: The upper half plane should be $\Bbb R\times [0,\infty)$.

Comment: Given two homeomorphisms $f,g$, their product $h(x,y)=(f(x),g(x))$ is also a homeomorphism.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\overline{\mathbb H^2}$ denote the upper half plane. $z\mapsto e^{i\psi }\dfrac{z-z_0}{z-z_0^*}$ where $\psi \in \mathbb R$ and Im$(z_0)>0$ is a good homeomorphism $\overline{\mathbb H^2}\rightarrow D$, where $D$ is the disk.

Then, to get to the upper half-disk compose that map with $(x,y)\mapsto \left(x, y+\dfrac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{2}\right)$ (Note here I'm passing between $\mathbb C$ and $\mathbb R^2$ using $z=x+iy$).

Your B looks like a rectangle with open boundaries and a closed boundary along the y-axis with holes at $(0,c)$ and $(0,d)$ but you might be able to show some homeomorphisms between rectangles and disks, but I'm not sure if that is what you meant.

What I chose to show here is that the upper-half plane is homeomorphic to the half-disk, but the rest of your question seems somewhat unclear as you might be asking about products of intervals.

Answer (score 0):

Given a ray $r$ in the upper half-plane $A$, we can consider the intersection $R=r\cap B$ of the ray with the open half-disk. If $(a,b)\in R$ we can send it to $\frac{1}{1-|(a,b)|}(a,b)$, where $|(a,b)|=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ is the distance from $(a,b)$ to the origin. You can check that this is a homeomorphism that stretches $R$ to $r$ (try drawing a picture to see how this "moves"). But this map works to stretch any ray in $B$ to a ray in $A$ simultaneously (picture the boundary of $B$ being stretched to infinity). Taking the domain of this map $(a,b)\mapsto\frac{1}{1-|(a,b)|}(a,b)$ to be $B$ instead of just a single ray in $B$, you can check that this is a homeomorphism from $B$ to $A$.